# Vuejs check for a null or undefined value in a method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I don't understand why I can't do

```
openAndFillModalSoin(soin)
        {
            this.show = true,   

            this.vDate = soin.date,
            this.vCategorie = soin.categoriesoin.name,
            //This can be null
            if(soin.rabaisraion){
                this.vReasonReduction = soin.rabaisraison.id;
            }

            this.vPaiement = soin.moyendepaiement.nam,
            this.vRefer = soin.referedBy,
            //This can be null aswell
            this.vGiftCard = soin.boncadeau.id,
            this.vVoucher = soin.bonreduction.id;

            this.vID = soin.id;
        },
```

The "if" parts doesn't work, it asks for an expression.

[image: If in method]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have commas instead of semicolons ending the preceding line.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry I'm having trouble with the use of semicolons and commas in js

Answer (score 1):

```
if(soin.rabaisraion){
                this.vReasonReduction = soin.rabaisraison.id;
            }
```

This this code will run when the following is NOT TRUE
soin.rabaisraion is the number 0, false, null, undefined, or an empty string.

To reiterate, the string 'false', the string '0' and and an array (empty or not) are all true.

Also, if soin is null or undefined, that will be a runtime error.

Perhaps you want this:

```
if(soin && soin.rabaisraion){
   this.vReasonReduction = soin.rabaisraison.id;
}
```

Regardless, add a log before to see what's going on:

```
console.log('checking soin', soin)
console.log('checking boolean soin', !!soin)
if(soin && soin.rabaisraion){
   this.vReasonReduction = soin.rabaisraison.id;
}
```

The '!!' will force the value to boolean.

Comment: Actually, I can't even compile. I'll add a screen in edit

Answer (score 0):

```
//check undefined Array
if (typeof myArray === "undefined") {
    alert("myArray is undefined");
}

// check undefined object
if (typeof myObj === "undefined") {
    alert("myObj is undefined");
}

//check object property
if (typeof myObj.some_property === "undefined") {
    alert("some_property is undefined");
}
```